# Special letters ÆØÅ shows as question mark

Tags: php, html, css

I have an about.php page where letters like ÆØÅ shows up as black question marks.
I also have a timeline.php where i use ÆØÅ but it works fine.

Im using UTF-8 but nothing changes.

Comment: To make the browser use the correct encoding, add an HTTP header like this:

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
or put the encoding in a meta tag:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
Alternatively you could try to read from the database in another encoding (UTF-8, preferably) or convert the text with iconv().

Comment: Tried to use the meta tag you said but nothing changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

Change the meta tag to declare `windows-1252` instead of `UTF-8.`